# Color problem in Filmic Log Encoding base

Tags: rendering, light, filmic-blender

I'm quite new in Blender and I saw Filmic light render in some tutorials.

I installed it but I have a problem with colors. Then absolutely don't match with those I input in material. Do you know how to resolve that ?

[image: With Filmic]
With Filmic

[image: With RGB]
With RGB

Comment: Why should they match?

Comment: Please consider that with Filmic Log there is an option for "Look", you may find that if you adjust it to "Base Contrast" or another setting the scene will look similar to what you have before, if you leave it at "None" you can have undesirable results with your scenes.

Comment: How the material looks will depend largely on the lighting for the scene combined with what kind of color transform is set in the color management section. What you call "color" on the material settings should be thought as Albedo (or reflectance...i.e how much of the light does the object reflect?). An object's color will be different if there is a bright light shining on it as opposed to a dim one. On top of that the different looks used in filmic blender will affect the contrast and saturation of the scene. For more info please read: read

Comment: @NickBosse Thank you very much, that exactly what I searched. :)

cegaton I know but here I was in the exactly same configuration. But It's solved now. Thank you ;)